# How to switch stdin dynamically? -> radare2

Tags: linux, debugging, radare2

i'm aware the it is possible to set the stdin to the content of file defined in the project profile. What i'd want though, is the ability to change the stdin while debugging. Is there any way to do this on a linux system?

Basically i need this because my next input to debuggee is depending on one of it's former outputs. This means i'm unable to set the right stdin content before i start debugging.

In fact i need to set it while i am debugging!

Thank you very much!